# Cordova/PhoneGap Photo File Size

Tags: cordova

All,

I'm trying to get the file size (i.e. not the dimensions, but the actual file size in disk) of a photo using PhoneGap/Cordova 2. So far, the only way I can figure it out is through base64 conversion, then basic arithmetic on the bytes of the b64 string. However, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to get file size. TIA.

clarification: it must work on iOS 5 and Android 2.3.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yeah, if you have the URL to the image from the Camera.getPicture command you pass it to the window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL command who's success callback is called with a FileEntry object. Then you call the "file" method of FileEntry which calls the success callback with a File object then you can look at the size property of the File object.

Something like....

```
function takePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(gotPhoto, onError, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA });
}

function gotPhoto(imageUri) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageUri, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
            console.log("Size = " + fileObj.size);
        });
    });
}
```

that should work but I just wrote the code off the top of my head.

Comment: Looks legit. I'm gonna give it a go and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work on iOS 5 or 5.1 or Android 2.3 (or older). Thx nonetheless, though.

Comment: Hey, take a look at my answer again. I had a syntax error that I fixed up. Also, I ran it myself this morning and it correctly reports the file size of the image.

Comment: Simon, I'll give it another go. But I think the problem is that neither iOS 5.x nor Android 2.3.x WebViews implement the W3C File API.

Comment: But if you are using PhoneGap/Cordova then we monkey patch support for the W3C File system spec into our web view. I should know I wrote the Android version myself.

Comment: Ah gotcha ;) It's somewhat of a undocumented feature. Thanks much, anyway.

Comment: Nope, it's all right there on the docs site http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Comment: This is not a fault of PhoneGap but more of the File API spec, imo. You have File, FileReader, FileWriter, requestFileSystem, resolveLocalFileSystemURI and so on and their use seems to blur and not entirely clear to me. I've read through that doc page at least a dozen times and had you not pointed out to use the function, I wouldn't have seen it.