# File size not able to read when images is choosed from image album

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my phonegap application(android version 4.4.2)  i need to pick image form sdcard. In this i am unable to read the image size and name. My code is like.

```
function getSkiImage(id,source){ 
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI){ 
        alert(imageURI); 
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, function(fileEntry) { 
            alert(fileEntry); 
            fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) { 
                alert(fileObj.size); 

            }); 
        }); 


// tried this also
/*window.requestFileSystem(imageURI, 0, function(data) { 
    alert(data.size); 

}, fail); */ 


}, fail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI, 
    sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY }); 
}
```

In my android device(v 4.4.2) album shows like "Recent", "Drive", "Images","Gallery",...when select image from gallery then only the image size is getting..other than Gallery image size is not able to get..

refered this but not get success

[Cordova/PhoneGap Photo File Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993043/cordova-phonegap-photo-file-size)

**In phonegap doc they say :**

> Android 4.4 only: Android 4.4 introduced a new Storage Access
>   Framework that makes it easier for users to browse and open documents
>   across all of their preferred document storage providers. Cordova has
>   not yet been fully integrated with this new Storage Access Framework.
>   Because of this, the getPicture() method will not correctly return
>   pictures when the user selects from the "Recent", "Drive", "Images",
>   or "External Storage" folders when the destinationType is FILE_URI.
>   However, the user will be able to correctly select any pictures if
>   they go through the "Gallery" app first. Potential workarounds for
>   this issue are documented on this StackOverflow question. Please see
>   CB-5398 to track this issue.
>
> Android uses intents to launch the camera activity on the device to
>   capture images, and on phones with low memory, the Cordova activity
>   may be killed. In this scenario, the image may not appear when the
>   Cordova activity is restored.

Comment: What errors does it show? Have you looked at the File plugin on Cordova? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html

Comment: @smj2393 nothing shown...

Comment: Question, are you trying to test this on a real device or are you trying it on emulator?

Comment: @Gajotres in my nexus device v 4.4.2

Comment: Nice, now tell me when you first open menu (which will allow you to select an image) which image galleries is your mobile phone showing you? Trust me this is an important question

Comment: For example Android UI will open a gallery view and it will allow you to select specific gallery.

Comment: @Gajotres  return pictures  from the "Recent", "Drive", "Images","Gallery",...

Comment: @Gajotres i got the point when select image from photos or gallery it shows image size but other than this not shown..

Comment: @Gajotres what is the solution for other folders..

Comment: @Ela are you trying to take live picture or same picture from your gallery?

Comment: Aha you are trying to open it from your SD card, then you are using wrong code

Comment: Take a look at an example Kathir provided you below

Comment: hi @Ela try this and let me know

Comment: wt @Gajotres ?.......

Comment: @Gajotres sdcard means like http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture

Comment: @Gajotres now look at my edited post..

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

    // Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // PhoneGap is ready to be used!
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);
    }


    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      alert(imageURI);

      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

      largeImage.style.display = 'block';


      largeImage.src = imageURI;
      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, rfail);


      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, onResolveSuccess, fail);
    }

    function rfail(e){
        alert(e);
    }
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }
    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        console.log(fileSystem.name);
    }
    function bytesToSize(bytes) {
        var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
        if (bytes == 0) return 'n/a';
        var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
        return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
    };
    function onResolveSuccess(fileEntry) {


        filenameofajax=fileEntry.name;

        var efail = function(evt) {
            console.log("File entry error  "+error.code);
        };
        var win=function(file) {
            console.log(file);
            for (var i in file){
                alert(i+""+file[i]);
            }
            alert(bytesToSize(file.size));

        };
        fileEntry.file(win, efail);
    }
    function efail(e) {
        alert("esa")
    }
    function fail(e) {
        alert("sa")
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    // 
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

check this