# Getting Error on selecting image from photogallery in phonegap Android app

Tags: android, cordova, android-gallery

I want to select an image from the photogallery for that I had return a code below:

```
function galleryPhoto()
{
sessionStorage.removeItem('imagepath');
navigator.camera.getPicture(onCameraSuccess,onCameraError,{quality:75,sourceType:Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,destinationtype:Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,allowEdit:true,encodingType:Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,targetWidth:320,targetHeight:480,correctOrientation: false});
}
```

When I try to run the app in device with Android 4.4.2 its showing me following error :

```
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500): Process: com.sacpl.nesso, PID: 15500
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=50, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content: flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.sacpl.nesso/com.sacpl.nesso.NessoSacplActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3942)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3992)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:156)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at org.apache.cordova.FileUtils.getMimeType(FileUtils.java:989)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher.onActivityResult(CameraLauncher.java:397)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.onActivityResult(DroidGap.java:806)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5535)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3938)
09-19 10:52:53.874: E/AndroidRuntime(15500):    ... 11 more
```

But its working in 4.0.4 and lower version properly 
Any Idea is appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this question at the bottom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736419/file-size-not-able-to-read-when-images-is-choosed-from-image-album

Comment: the solution is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5398