# Can't get file size via file plugin

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

I used cordova file plugin to create a file inside a folder. I'm able to access it, but before uploading it to the server I need to get its file size. So I try to list all files inside the folder. But I'm not able to get the file size of that specific file.

```
ListAudioFiles() {
    File.listDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'folder/Audios').then(
        (allFiles) => {
            // do something
             console.log("file listing success", allFiles)
             /*here i could get list of all file that are present in my folder*
        }).catch(
        (err) => {
            // do something
            console.log("file listing err", err)
        });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the `resolveLocalFileSystemURI` method like described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993043/cordova-phonegap-photo-file-size)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova/PhoneGap Photo File Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993043/cordova-phonegap-photo-file-size)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
file.getMetadata((metaData) => {
   console.log(metaData.size);
});
```

Complete example

```
ListAudioFiles() {
    File.listDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'folder/Audios').then(
        (allFiles) => {
            for (let file of allFiles) {
                file.getMetadata((metaData) => {
                    console.log(metaData.size);
                });
            }
        }).catch(
        (err) => {
            // do something
            console.log("file listing err", err)
        });
}
```